# iOS 6 - How can I get the "release to refresh" animation thing? like in mail?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

In mail app, we can now `drag the view down` and `release to refresh`, like shown in the picture below.

Is this a standard thing I can get from SDK?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the new iOS6 [`UIRefreshControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) class to do that.

```
yourUITableViewController.refreshControl = [[[UIRefreshControl alloc] init] autorelease];
[yourUITableViewController.refreshControl addTarget:yourTableView action:@selector(reloadData) forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Is this new in iOS 6, or it exists long time ago

Comment: Yep, new, as stated in my answer already (**the new iOS6** `UIRefreshControl` **class**)… ;)

Answer (score 2):

If u need customized refresh control,

[ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl)

thanks,

Naveen Shan