# How to replicate the "pulled chewing gum" appearance of UIRefreshControl?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ios6, core-graphics

In iOS 6's Mail app there is a "release to refresh" animation that looks like a chewing gum or rubber being pulled then released. Anybody know how to replicate drawing of this control using Core Graphics?

The background is I'd like to replicate this behavior on a mac and there isn't any equivalent of `UIRefreshControl` in Mountain Lion.

Note: this is a continuation to [iOS 6 - How can I get the "release to refresh" animation thing? like in mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515236/ios-6-how-can-i-get-the-release-to-refresh-animation-thing-like-in-mail)

Comment: Looks like two circles connected by a pair of bezier paths to me. Vary the circles size and the bend in the side paths and shrink the image of the refresh arrow according to the "stretch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any implementation of UIRefreshControl (or equivalent) for Mountain Lion at this moment. However, there are implementations of equivalent controls for iOS 4 and iOS 5 (because those systems doesn't have UIRefreshControl). So you can try doing a port of those codes to OSX.

I have found 2 projects on github:

https://github.com/ishkawa/ISRefreshControl

https://github.com/dbsGen/SlimeRefresh

Comment: SlimeRefresh looks promising. Anyway in the meantime I've decided to use a circular determinate progress indicator instead: [Pull to refresh that goes both ways](http://cutecoder.org/programming/pull-refresh-ways/).